# study case in C++. Abstract class and instance

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I have to understand why this program in C++ isn't working.  There were many other errors but I corrected them.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
    public : 
    X(int a) : a(a) {}
    virtual void f(ostream& flot) const { flot << " X::f" << endl; }
    virtual void g() const = 0;

    private :
    int a;
};


class Z : public X {
    void h() const {cout << "Z::h" << endl;}
    public :
    Z() : X(0) {}
    void f(ostream& flot) const override { flot << "Z::f" << endl;}
    void g() const override  {cout << "Z::g" << endl;} 
};

void operator<< (ostream& flot, const Z& z ) { z.f(flot);}



int main() {
    Z z;
    cout << z << endl;
    Z z2();
    z2.h();
    X* x1;
    x1->f(cout);
    z.h();

}
```

You can't write cout << z << endl; because z does not exist as a normal object, is it correct? it is a kind of imaginary object ? at the contrary of z2 which is constructed and does exists. Can you tell me if I am right?

And I don't understand why the two last lines:

```
x1->f(cout);
z.h();
```

are not problematic. I thought that x1 does not exists (as z). So why can you call a method for x1?

And for z.h(), the only problem is that h is, here, in this context, private. But if it would have been inside the public part, it wouldn't be a problem. Why ??? Isn't z imaginary so you can't use any method on it?

Comment: `Z z2();` this probably doesn't do what you think it does. see [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: You are supposed to return `std::ostream` object back when you overload `operator <<`. Does this line `cout << z << endl;` compile? From my understanding, compiler would see `std::cout << z`, the result of this operation is `void`, and then it sees `void << std::endl`, which is obvious error.

Comment: Did you try to compile this? Did you analyze the compile errors? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: Please explain what you understand by the concept imaginary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Z z;
```

This defines and constructs an object `z` of type `Z`. The default constructor is called.

```
cout << z << endl;
```

This calls `operator<<` for `(cout, z)`, and then uses the return value of that to call `operator<<` for it and `endl`. The return value is void, so the second call cannot work. Your `operator<<` needs to return the output stream for this to work.

```
Z z2();
```

This defines a function `z2` that takes no arguments and returns a `Z`. Not a variable, but not actually wrong itself.

```
z2.h();
```

At this point it's wrong, because `z2` is a function and not an object. Try removing the parentheses, or changing the previous line to `Z z2 = Z();`.

```
X* x1;
```

This defines a variable `x1` of type `X*`. It's uninitialized.

```
x1->f(cout);
```

This calls the function `X::f` on your uninitialized pointer, which is undefined behaviour. Read undefined behaviour as "could do anything, avoid".

```
z.h();
```

This tries to call the function `h` on `z`, but it's a private function. You'll get a compile error because it's private and not accessible from `main` context.

Answer (score 1):

To get `cout` to accept a `Z` object after the operator `<<`, overload the  operator `<<` to recognize an `ostream` object on the left and a `Z` on the right. The overloaded `<<` operator function must then be declared as a friend of class `Z`.

The first error is solved by adding the following declaration to Z class:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Z& z);
```

On the other hand, if you want to invoke the method `h` on the instance `z2` you have to make `h`  public method, in your code it is `private` by default.

As a final note, you should receive a segmentation fault at the sentence:

```
x1->f(cout);
```

because the pointer x1 point to a non-allocated object.

Comment: Why "must then be declared as a friend of class Z"? It does not use any private members of Z in this case.

Comment: You are right, in this case, the friend declaration is not needed, the error was related to bad definition of the overloaded function (it should return ostream&)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "imaginary" object in C++. Either an object is created or it is not. There is nothing wring with `Z z;`. Since the object exists, there is no problem in using the function `Z::h()` once you make it `public`.

`Z z2();` doesn't create an object as you intend, since it is parsed as a function taking no argument and returng an object of `Z`. This is, as pointed out in the first comment, the case of most vexing parse.

Regarding the `cout`, the operator `<<` should be able to print stuff from your class. Hence, you need to make the operator a friend of your class.

Also, since `x1` is declared but not initialized, you will have undefined behavior for `x1->f();`. Also, you can't even do something like `X* x1 = new X(0);` because `X::g()` is pure virtual, and the class `X` is an abstract base class.

The following code would run wothout issues:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
    public :
    X(int a) : a(a) {}
    virtual ~X() {}
    virtual void f(ostream& flot) const { flot << " X::f" << endl; }
    virtual void g() const {};

    private :
    int a;
};


class Z : public X {
    public :
    Z() : X(0) {}
    void f(ostream& flot) const override { flot << "Z::f" << endl;}
    void g() const override  {cout << "Z::g" << endl;}
    void h() const {cout << "Z::h" << endl;}
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Z &z);
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& flot, const Z& z ) { z.f(flot); return flot;}

int main() {
    Z z;
    cout << z << endl;
    //Z z2();
    //z2.h();
    X * x1 = new X(0);
    x1->f(cout);
    z.h();
    delete x1;
    return 0;
}
```